# Ploting scatter marker symbols from an image in plotly R

Tags: r, image, plotly, r-plotly

I want my marker symbols to be images from a file instead of default symbols as listed [here](http://www.r-graph-gallery.com/125-the-plotlys-symbols/).

I searched but couldn't find a way to use an image file for the symbols.
Let's say I have a `data.frame`

```
dt<-data.frame(seq(1,10,by=1))
```

and

```
dt1<-data.frame(seq(1,20,by=1))
```

Ploting using:

```
plot_ly(dt, x=dt$seq.1..10..by...1., y=dt1$seq.1..20..by...1.) %>%
add_trace(dt, x = dt$seq.1..10..by...1., y = dt$seq.1..10..by...1., type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers',
marker = list(symbol=~2,size = 15, opacity = 0.5, colors="black"))
```

Gives the output as:
[image]

Here I can change the numbers at `symbol=` from `~1` to `~32` as listed but I want to use a custom image instead. 
Any idea on how to do it. Use any Image you want from the web as an example.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could probably adapt this:

```
plot_ly(dt, x=dt$seq.1..10..by...1., y=dt1$seq.1..20..by...1.) %>%
  add_trace(dt, x = dt$seq.1..10..by...1., y = dt$seq.1..10..by...1., type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers',
            marker = list(symbol=~2,size = 15, opacity = 0.5, colors="white")) %>%
  layout(
    images = list(
      list(source = "https://images.plot.ly/language-icons/api-home/python-logo.png",
           xref = "x",
           yref = "y",
           x= 1,
           y= 1,
           sizex = 0.2,
           sizey = 0.2,
           opacity = 0.8,
           layer = "above"
      ),

      list(source = "https://images.plot.ly/language-icons/api-home/matlab-logo.png",
           xref = "x",
           yref = "y",
           x = 2,
           y = 2,
           sizex = 0.5,
           sizey = 0.5,
           opacity = 0.8
      ),

      list(source =  "https://images.plot.ly/language-icons/api-home/r-logo.png",
           xref = "x",
           yref = "y",
           x = 2.5,
           y = 3.5,
           sizex = 1,
           sizey = 1,
           opacity = 0.8
      )
    )
  )
```

Comment: nah still not getting it.

Comment: @SamAct what do mean? The code is not working or this is not what you want?

Comment: @SamAct weird it is working for me. I am using plotly_4.7.1

Comment: Donno what the problem is with my viewer, but if it open it in HTML I can see the pictures. However, pictures are beside the points I wanted the picture as points itself. Any changes I can make?

Comment: As far as I know I don't it is possible with `r-plotly`. But it might with `plotly`.